# Convert .csv file with multiple values in each line to one per line

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv file with multiple values on each line like this

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I would like to convert it to

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Is there any quick, easy way to do this in linux terminal?

Comment: *"Is there any quick, easy way to do this in Linux terminal?"* - Yes. You are expected to perform basic research and make an effort. Please show the relevant code and state where you are having problems. Also see [Why is the “how to move the turtle in logo” question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158289) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: +1 jww : I found a solution in 30seconds by asking myself the good questions, which are not hard at all. Show some efforts so I will remove my downvote

Answer (score 1):

```
cat mycsvfile.txt | tr ',' '\n' > aaa.txt <enter>
```

Just Found this (http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=2742)

Comment: Put the `cat` back in its box; there's no need for it here: `<mycsvfile.txt tr ',' '\n' >aaa.txt`

Comment: Congratulations for your effort using stackoverflow the way it has to. You found your way with existing questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

In only one command you can use `sed -i 's/,/\n/g' file.txt`

This will replace, in your entire `file.txt`, the char `,` by the char `\n`.
You may find explanation on how this command works on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/20416).